# how to Joint feature via online boosting

Tags: python, machine-learning, adaboost, boosting

I would like to combine two features using online boosting.

I read more papers that explain online boosting and joint features using boosting, papers are:

[Identification of a specific person using color, height, and gait features for a person following robot](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0921889015303225)
,

[People tracking in RGB-D Data with on-line boosted target models](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221066268_People_tracking_in_RGB-D_Data_with_on-line_boosted_target_models),

[On-line Boosting and Vision](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1640768),

[Fast RGB-D people tracking for service robots](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10514-014-9385-0),

[Boosting with a Joint Feature Pool from Different Sensors](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-04667-4_7),
[Convolutional Channel Features-Based Person Identification for Person Following Robots](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/325854919_Convolutional_Channel_Features-Based_Person_Identification_for_Person_Following_Robots), with its code [here](https://github.com/koide3/monocular_person_following)

Here explain about [AdaBoostClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.AdaBoostClassifier.html)

I understood it theoretically but I can't implement it in python. My experience with c++ is zero.
Any one help me, this is my simple code:

```
import cv2
import time
import numpy as np

person_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(('haarcascade_upperbody.xml'))
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
    r, frame = cap.read()
    #================================color feature===================
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    green_lower = np.array([0, 0, 0], np.uint8)
    green_upper = np.array([180, 255, 30], np.uint8)
    green = cv2.inRange(hsv, green_lower, green_upper)
    (_, contours, hierarchy) = cv2.findContours(green, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    for pic, contour in enumerate(contours):
        area1 = cv2.contourArea(contour)
        if (area1 > 300):
            # print area1

            x1, y1, w1, h1 = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
            img = cv2.rectangle(frame, (x1, y1), (x1 + w1, y1 + h1), (255, 0, 0), 2)
            cv2.putText(frame, "green Colour", (x1, y1), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (255, 0, 0))
    #====================================upperbody feature=============       
    if r:
        start_time = time.time()
        frame = cv2.resize(frame,(640,360)) # Downscale to improve frame rate
        gray_frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY) # Haar-cascade classifier needs a grayscale image
        rects = person_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray_frame)

        for (x, y, w, h) in rects:
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (x,y), (x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)
        cv2.imshow("preview", frame)
    k = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if k & 0xFF == ord("q"): # Exit condition
        break
```

Comment: What *exactly* is your *issue* and your *question*? "Here is my code but it doesn't work" is hardly helpful or informative.